# What's the best Cloud Development Platform (if there is such a thing)? (Ruby, CouchDB)

Tags: ruby, web-services, couchdb

first of all one confession: i hate to run software local. i really do (other than the OS and a browser).

ok, about my question: i'm a pretty sophisticated JS coder and a pretty senior PHP dev. my old school dev. setup basically was: code everything online (via textwrangler and FTP upload) on on dev-(sub)domain. if it works clone (download and upload) it to another domain. works great for one person (or 2 to 3 person teams).

i wanted to leave PHP behind now for many years, non the less i come back to it for my quick and dirty web-apps projects (i.e.: miniqr.com). not because i like it, but because there is no install this, install that, set up this, config that, run that, run this overhead. (it's ugly and compared to other setups - ugly, but it just works (most of the time good enough)).

so what i'm searching for is the same thing but with ruby (framework sinatra - as a db i want to run couchdb)

is there a provider which offers such a thing (maybe even with an useable online code editor)?

i know that there are upsides using run localy, deploy anywhere, git push pull whatever, but for my needs this is just overhead.

how (and where) would you set up such a (dirty) cloud development environment?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really based upon your needs. I suggest looking into CouchApp with CouchDB. This will allow you to use JavaScript and HTML as your front end and then CouchDB as your web/app/DB server. You can sign up on [CouchOne](http://www.couchone.com/get) and get started on your project right away. I have worked on a few projects with this combination and I love it.